# Create incremental number column in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe with incremental float values

```
   Number
0 0.679484 
1 0.079027 
2 0.003132 
3 0.092761 
4 0.055500 
5 0.055500 
6 0.055500 
7 0.003132
```

i need to add a new column assigning number between 1 -5 based on existing column on the basis of their values in ascending order.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Series.rank](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.rank.html) with method 'dense' which assigns rank from minimum to maximum incrementing by 1 between groups

```
df['rank'] = df['Number'].rank(method = 'dense').astype(int)


    Number      rank
0   0.679484    5
1   0.079027    3
2   0.003132    1
3   0.092761    4
4   0.055500    2
5   0.055500    2
6   0.055500    2
7   0.003132    1
```

Comment: thanks... one thing how does dense stop at 5 .. my entire dataframe has more than 1000 rows but i need to limit the ranking till only 50.

Comment: Rank does not have a limit parameter so you cannot control the number. What you can do is filter the data after assigning rank. df[df['Rank'] <= 50] will only show rows where rank is less than or equal to 50

Comment: Second option is to sort the data first and apply rank to first 50 rows

Comment: thanks Vaishali... I have come across "pd.qcut" which seems to work fine... with my issue..